# Ionic 2 - returns [object,object]

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

This is my array push:

```
let results = this.allExercises[i];
this.dataArray.push(results);
```

I give navParams with a page push like this:

```
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
        'exercisesDone': this.dataArray
    });
```

I retrieve them in my HomePage like this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params:NavParams) {
      if(params.get("exercisesDone")){
        this.exerciseIsDone = params.get("exercisesDone");
        console.log('exerciseDone: ', this.exerciseIsDone);
      }
  }
```

With this output:
[image]

And in my html I do this:

```
  <p>{{ exerciseIsDone }}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let b of exerciseIsDone; let i = index">{{ b }}</div>
```

With this as outcome:

```
<p>[object Object], [object Object],[object Object]</p>
<div>[object Object]</div>
<div>[object Object]</div>
```

How can i print the values of the array?

Comment: `{{b.exercise}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing object. It should be:

```
<div *ngFor="let b of exerciseIsDone; let i = index">{{b.done}}{{b.exercise}}{{b.path}}</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't print anything

Comment: Ohh nvm I first had to select them -.-''